# every time the game started my FOV of cinemachine virtual cam always become 0 in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so im trying to make an aiming mechanic on my game with unity engine, it works well. but the problem is every time the game started, the FOV always become zero. it will be normal again when i press right click on my mouse.

here is my code:

```
[Header("Zoom")]
public float zoomInFov = 40;
[HideInInspector] public float hipFov;
[HideInInspector] public float currentFov;
public float fovSmoothSpeed = 10;

void Start()
{
    hipFov = vCam.m_Lens.FieldOfView;
}

//Aiming
if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
{
    animator.SetBool("isAiming", true);
    currentFov = zoomInFov;
}

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
{
    animator.SetBool("isAiming", false);
    currentFov = hipFov;
}
vCam.m_Lens.FieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(vCam.m_Lens.FieldOfView, currentFov, fovSmoothSpeed * 
Time.deltaTime);
```

please help me, i'd appreciate any advice :)

Comment: Check the value of the FOV in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Start()
{
    hipFov = vCam.m_Lens.FieldOfView;
    currentFov = hipFov;
}
```

Comment: yeah i just realized, all i had to do is give a value of FOV in the start method. thanks btw